# Maven Wagon plugin: Can wagon:upload upload to multiple locations?

Tags: maven, wagon, maven-wagon-plugin

I'm looking into the [Maven Wagon Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) to attempt uploading some artifacts to remote UNC Server shares (`\\servername\share\directory\to\put\to`), and I have gotten it configured to work like so in the POM:

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-file</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>upload-jar-to-folder</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>upload</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <fromDir>${project.build.directory}</fromDir>
      <includes>*</includes>
      <url>file://localhost///${servername}/${sharename}</url>
      <toDir>directory/to/put/artifact</toDir>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ...
</build>
```

This works great ***for one server*** when I pass in `-Dservername=x -Dsharename=y`, but how can I scale it out so I can run a deploy for QA or Prod where I have multiple servers to deploy to?

I've considered (and written) a script to run `mvn wagon:upload -Penvironment#` multiple times--once for each server--but this seems flawed to me. If I'm shelling out to a script to handle this process, I  could just as well script out the entire deploy, too. However, this takes away from the usefulness of Wagon (and Maven)...

Is there a way to run multiple `<executions>` for one goal?  For instance, running multiple profile configured `wagon:upload` tasks when I just run `mvn deploy -Pqa`?

Comment: Instead of uploading individually, can't your servers just share a network drive? They should probably be in the same network and see each other. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work.  The folder that I deploy to is the Weblogic installation's 'autodeploy' folder, which is specific for each instance.  I'm not against doing that, but I don't know if I've seen it done before and wouldn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use multiple profiles you could just use: `mvn deploy -Denv=qa` and trigger some profiles on this property and define the configuration for your severs in the profiles. For this kind of profile activation look at

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

and search for

-Denvironment=test

Here's an example POM which does two executions of the maven-antrun-plugin in one build:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>q5328617</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>qa</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <id>qa1</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                      <execution>
                        <id>qa1</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo level="info">Executing qa1</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                      </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>qa</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <id>qa2</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                      <execution>
                        <id>qa2</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo level="info">Executing qa2</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                      </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Does profile activation allow multiple executions of the same plugin?  In the above, the only thing that changes between deploying to one server to another is the url.  I would want to run 2, 3, or more executions of the above plugin in one fell swoop to get that installed on all servers.

Comment: Yes it does (just tried ;-) ! I edited my answer and added an example.

Comment: excellent!  I will try this out on my project for now.  It is a bit verbose, but it's at least possible.